# how to decrease the decimal places in the mantissa part of an exponential number in an output in python

Tags: python, numpy

THE CODE

```
avogadro = 6.0225e23 # define Avogadro number
at_wt = 63.55
print ("atomic weight of copper = 63.55")
print("weight of an atom = atomic weight/Avogadro's number")
x = at_wt/ avogadro
print ("Weight of one atom of copper = {}".format(x) )

THE OUTPUT
atomic weight of copper = 63.55
weight of an atom = atomic weight/Avogadro's number
Weight of one atom of copper = 1.0552096305520962e-22
```

I am interested that in the output 1.0552096305520962e-22, I would like that the mantissa part of the exponential number displays only 3 decimal points instead of so many. Hence, what command should I use to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Use a better [format](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#formatspec) string:

```
print ("Weight of one atom of copper = {:0.3e}".format(x) )
```